# vba updateable shape controls in master shape

Tags: vba, visio

I am having a bear of a time finding an answer to what seems like a simple question. I am using Visio 2010. I need to have something like text box that I can update through VBA. I have to code to do it

```
shape.CellsU("Prop.Memory").Formula = """256 MB"""
```

for example (shape is a variable in this case). The problem is that I can't find out how to tie a control, like a text box or label, to a user defined property like "Prop.memory" in this case. I thought it might be a data graphic but adding a data graphic is disabled for me.

Michael.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have a solution. It is an odd one but it might work. The problem is that you cannot apply Data graphics when you have the master open in edit mode. what you can do is drop the master on the sheet based on the recordset. now you can add data graphics because it has a record source (I am guessing). I made the changes I need to that layout that I needed. I then dragged that shape to the stencil to become a new master. it will maintain the data links. it seems like an odd way to go about it but it does work. I might be good for now.

update: this didn't work for what I needed. I did find the way, though, on this site: [Creating custom Visio shapes](http://support.d-tools.com/02_SI5/User_Guide/08Visio_Interface/zTips_Tricks/Custom_Visio_Shapes)

Once you create the shape with the right fields, you have to use something like the following code to update it via VBA:

```
shp.cells("prop.Memory").Formula= chr(34) & "256 MB" & chr(34)
```

where shp is a visio shape

I just wanted to be the solution that I found is out there.

Cheers, Michael.